# LibGDX How to combine 2 textures in single location for multitexturing, using Sprites and SpriteBatch

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader, lwjgl

Using LibGDX, I've written a very simple (and my first) fragment shader which is to have two different textures set, the first being an image to draw to the screen and the second is an alpha-transparency mask. Here is the fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_mask;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec4 maskColor = texture2D(u_mask, v_texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        vec3(v_color * texColor),
        maskColor.a
    );
}
```

u_texture is the image to draw and u_mask is the texture with the transparency information.

However, what I really want to do is utilise the `Sprite` and `TextureAtlas` classes to refer to a couple of `TextureRegion` instances for the shader. Here is my rendering code:

```
shaderBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
shaderBatch.begin();

// ... some housekeeping code ...

Sprite overlapAlphaMask = maskTextureAtlas.createSprite("mask", 4);
Sprite overlapSprite = spriteTextureAtlas.createSprite("some-tile", 8);
// Or some other index in the texture atlas

overlapAlphaMask.getTexture().bind(1);
alphaMaskShader.setUniformi("u_mask", 1);

overlapSprite.getTexture().bind(0);
alphaMaskShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);

shaderBatch.draw(overlapSprite, worldX, worldY, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Although this is at least running and rendering something, it is picking up the wrong texture region from the `maskTextureAtlas`. My guess is there's more to do here as the shader is not going to have any knowledge about the overlapAlphaMask sprite - how to draw it, what the texture coords are, etc.

I'm assuming the `SpriteBatch.draw()` method is taking care of picking up the correct information from the `overlapSprite` that's passed in, so I expect the `vec2 v_texCoords` in the shader has been set correctly to draw this, but these co-ordinates are wrong for the 2nd texture / sampler2D uniform property. This is my first attempt at using shaders so I'm sure I'm missing something basic!

--- Update ---

So far my googling has revealed I may need to be setting something more via the vertex shader. I'm using this (default?) libGDX vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

Comment: If there's only one set of texture coordinates, are you sure that both texture atlases have the sprite you want in the same location?

Comment: It's not on the same location, how do I get the information through to the shaders for this? To make it more difficult, the sprite contains translations and rotations that are different from each other

Comment: Just create another attribute.  You'll need to add it to your vertex buffers, vertex arrays, vertex shader, and pass it through to the fragment shader where you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dietrich Epp has pointed out, what I require is to send the extra texture co-ordinates via vertex buffers through to the vertex and pixel shader. I've managed to achieve this by writing my own implementation of the `SpriteBatch` class which has two `texture`s set at a time (not `TextureRegion`s) and batches drawing of these with a couple of slightly extended shaders, as follows:

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord1;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords0;
varying vec2 v_texCoords1;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords0 = a_texCoord0;
    v_texCoords1 = a_texCoord1;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

This is the default vertex shader but with the `attribute vec2 a_texCoord` replaced with a set of two tex co-ords, and resulting `varying vec2 v_texCoordsX` for passing along to the fragment shader. This extra `attribute vec2` is then sent in through the vertex buffer.

Fragment Shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords0;
varying vec2 v_texCoords1;
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
uniform sampler2D u_texture1;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture0, v_texCoords0);
    vec4 maskColor = texture2D(u_texture1, v_texCoords1);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        vec3(v_color * texColor),
        maskColor.a
    );
}
```

Similarly, the fragment shader now receives two `sampler2D` textures to sample from, and a pair of texture co-ordinates to refer to for each.

The key to the changes in the `SpriteBatch` class is extending the `Mesh` definition in the constructor:

```
    mesh = new Mesh(Mesh.VertexDataType.VertexArray, false, size * 4, size * 6, new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2,
            ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE), new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked, 4, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE),
            new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0"),
            new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "1"));
```

The final line above is the new addition, a pair of co-ordinates for `a_texCoord1`. The `draw()` method is passed two `Sprite` or `TextureRegion` instances, and is extended slightly to pass in the 2 extra floats for each set of vertices per point/index to the vertex array. Finally a slight addition to the shader set up to bind both textures and set the uniforms as so:

```
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture0", 0);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture1", 1);
```

And it works! My temporary solution was to draw the two sprites to the screen over the top of each other writing transparency information into the display buffer, but due to `SpriteBatch` batching for each texture, and my images being split across several textures, this was resulting in an unacceptable loss of performance, which this solution has fixed :)

Comment: Hi Ross, Thank you for this solution, this sounds like exactly what I need. Do you have the source for the custom SpriteBatch? I have some trouble implementing the custom draw() method(s).

Comment: Sure, it's not great code, and it's over 4 years old so this might be different from current libgdx, I recommend doing a diff with the default sprite batch to see what's been added https://pastebin.com/p8vnWxH2

Comment: Thank you very much for the great example :) It brought me a lot further, but it's not exactly what I need. What I'm currently doing is rendering an alpha mask in a framebuffer based on my units locations. The texture is exactly my screen size. I would like to use this texture as an alphamask for everything I draw, but the alphamask texture should always be in screen coordinates.

An example: the alpha mask contains the following unit locations:
(2,3,10,20)
(1,7,10,20)

If I now render an object on 1,6,8,12 that should be partly alpha blended by the last unit. Do you know how to do this?